# Calling a member function pointer without using this

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've written the following class that looks up a keyword and executes the associated function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
class Example;

typedef std::map<
    std::string, void (Example::*)(const std::string &)> ExampleList;
typedef ExampleList::iterator ExampleIter;

class Example
{
public:
    ExampleList lut;
    Example()
    {
        lut["aaa"] = &Example::aaa;
        lut["bbb"] = &Example::bbb;
    }

    void lookup(const std::string& line)
    {
        // Get the keyword
        std::size_t keylen = line.find(' ', 0);
        std::string keyword = line;
        if (keylen != line.npos)
            keyword = line.substr(0, keylen);

        // Is it something we recognize
        ExampleIter eit = lut.find(keyword);
        if (eit == lut.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to handle " << keyword << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        // Found - execute the handler
        (this->*(eit->second))(line);  // << is there an alternative syntax without this?
    }

    void aaa(const std::string& info)
    {
        std::cout << "aaa" << std::endl;
    }
    void bbb(const std::string& info)
    {
        std::cout << "bbb" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example eg;
    eg.lookup("aaa");    // pass
    eg.lookup("bbb is legal"); // pass
    eg.lookup("bbbb is illegal"); // fail - bbbb not found
    eg.lookup("cc"); // fail cc not found
    eg.lookup("aaaa"); // fail aaaa not found 
}
```

At the end of the function lookup, I am executing the handler using

```
(this->*(eit->second))(line);
```

I'm just wondering whether it is possible to call the handler without `this->*`

Comment: No, is the short answer. But you could redesign to avoid using member function pointers. Maybe use `std::function` instead.

Comment: `std::invoke(eit->second, this, line);`.  You still need to specify `this`.

Comment: How else do you expect the pointed-to member function to receive the correct object?

Comment: With static member functions you could

Comment: Style note: rather than using `typedef`... `using ExampleList = std::map<std::string, void (Example::*)(const std::string &)>; using ExampleIter = ExampleList::iterator;`

Comment: @chris I know about using but the problem is the code has to build on 3 different compilers.  Unfortunately one of which is not quite C++11 so I have to use the syntax it understands.  Suppose I could derive from the map instead of having it as a member.   I'll have to try that out.

Comment: Why would you care about 7 characters in one place (9 if you count the requisite parentheses)?

Comment: @DavisHerring I was wondering whether there was another way of calling the ->* operator.  In most cases the **this->** does not need to be specified.  In this case, however, I need ->*, which is an operator in its own right so I can't just use *.

Comment: If someone wants to add an answer with No, I'll accept it and we can close this one.

Comment: As long as you stay in C++ (i.e. *not* having the object called from a C interface) it is possible to keep the this object pointer and the member function pointer together inside one std::function by using bind or lambda functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**: pointers to members, even to members of the current class type, do not have the **implicit `(*this).`** that the members themselves have (or rather the `(*this).*` they would need).  Fundamentally, this is because it would be impossible to (reliably) **distinguish** between use of the pointer and use of the referenced member:

```
struct X {
  int i;
  auto f() {
    int X::*p=&X::i;
    return p;  // does this return 'int X::*' or 'int'?
  }
};
```

This ambiguity can't arise with direct member access precisely because you have to use `&X::i` rather than just `&i` to form a pointer-to-member.  Consider also that such a pointer-to-member might point to a member of a **derived** class that `*this` doesn't even have.